# How to run TypeScript for validation without generating js files?

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript v2.0 and `ts-node`. I don't need js files, but I want use typescript for validation in my tests. So how can I run TypeScript for validation, without generating js files?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `--noEmit` flag.

```
tsc file.ts --noEmit
```

For validation purposes, you may also consider adding a linter compatible with TypeScript (such as [ESLint with TypeScript support](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/README.md)).